# Affect m students to n groups, but with constraints?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, constraints

I asked about the minimum cost maximum flow [several weeks ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124763/affect-m-students-to-n-groups). Kraskevich's answer was brilliant and solved my problem. I've [implemented it](http://64cases.com:8080/OptiWeb/) and it works fine (available only in French, sorry). Additionaly, the algorithm can handle the assignement of *i* (*i* > 1) projects to each student.

Now I'm trying something more difficult. I'd like to add constraints on choices. In the case one wants to affect *i* (*i* > 1) projects to each student, I'd like to be able to specify which projects are compatible (each other).

In the case some projects are not compatible, I'd like the algorithm to return the global optimum, i.e. affect *i* projects to each student maximizing global happiness **and** repecting compatibility constraints.

Chaining *i* times the original method (and checking constraints at each step) will not help, as it would only return a local optimum.

Any idea about the correct graph to work with ?

Comment: Your problem is not very well-defined.  How is global happiness calculated?

Comment: @CaptainCodeman you should read the [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28124763/affect-m-students-to-n-groups) to understand what I mean. It's about projects assigned to students based on their preferences. The global happiness here is the opposite of the cost calculated by that algorithm.

Comment: Yes I looked at your previous question, the scoring is not well-defined there either.  How do you calculate the cost there?  You just said that there is a priority list, but no mention of how cost is calculated from that.

Comment: Right, then. I've forgot to mention that I used the [Successive Shortest Path Algorithm](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=minimumCostFlow2). You can look at _Figure 4._ for an example calculation of the implied cost. In my case the costs of edges are defined as Kraskevich suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not solvable in polynomial time(unless `P = NP` or there are additional constraints).

Here is a polynomial time reduction from the maximum independent set problem(which is known to be NP-complete) to this one:

Given a graph `G` and a number `k`, do the following:

1. Create a project for each vertex in the graph `G` and say that two project are incompatible iff there is an edge between the corresponding vertices in `G`.
2. Create one student who likes each project equally(we can assume that the happiness each project gives to him is equal to `1`).
3. Find the maximum happiness using an algorithm that solves the problem stated in your question. Let's call it `h`.
4. A set of projects can be picked iff they all are compatible, which means that the picked vertices of `G` form an independent set(due to the way we constructed the graph).
5. Thus, `h` is equal to the size of the maximum independent set.
6. Return `h >= k`.

What does it mean in practice? It means that it is not reasonable to look for a polynomial time solution to this problem. There are several things that can be done:

1. If the input is small, you can use exhaustive search.
2. If it is not, you can use heuristics and/or approximations to find a relatively good solution(not necessary the optimal one, though).

Comment: Maximum independent set is not NP-complete in bipartite graphs.  (It is simply the complement of the minimum vertex cover which can be determined from a bipartite matching)

Comment: @CaptainCodeman There are no bipartite graphs here. Again, I reduce a maximum independent set problem for an arbitrary graph to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can stomach the library dependency, integer programming will be quicker and easier than anything you can implement yourself. All you have to do is formulate the original problem as an integer program and then add your ad hoc constraints at the end.